# Вывод списка дочерних категорий и товара находящихся в этих категориях

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Доброго время провождения!

Задача вывести список дочерних категорий и товары которые находятся в этих категориях на текущем уровне вложенности.

Имеется такой код который выводит все категории магазина игнорируя активную категорию.

```
                $args = array(

   'number'     => $number,

   'orderby'   => 'title',

   'order'     => 'ASC',

   'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,

   'include'   => $ids,
                  


);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

$count = count($product_categories);

if ( $count > 0 ){

   foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {

       echo '<h4><a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></h4>';

       $args = array(

           'posts_per_page' => -1,

           'tax_query' => array(

              'relation' => 'AND',

               array(

                   'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',

                   'field' => 'slug',

                   // 'terms' => 'white-wines'

                   'terms' => $product_category->slug

                )

           ),

           'post_type' => 'product',

           'orderby' => 'title,'

       );

       $products = new WP_Query( $args );

       echo "<ul>";

       while ( $products->have_posts() ) {

           $products->the_post();

           ?>

               <li>

                   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

                       <?php the_title(); ?>

                   </a>

               </li>

           <?php

       }

       echo "</ul>";

   }

}

?>
```

Есть понимание того что надо получить ID активной категории и получать нужный мне список, но мое знание php недостаточно что бы это реализовать. Накопал такой код, осталось понять как его применить правильно в коде описанном выше.

```
$current_term = get_queried_object();
    $terms = get_terms( [
        'taxonomy' => [ 'product_cat' ],
        'parent'         => $current_term->term_id,
    ] );
var_dump( $terms );
```

Надеюсь на ваши подсказки, в результате должна получиться примерно следующая структура:

Магазин > Продукты (Активная категория)

Фрукты (Дочерняя категория)

- Банан (Товар)
- Яблоко
- Груша

Овощи

- Картофель
- Лук
- Перец

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью  get_queried_object получилось получить массив объектов текущей категории.
В аргументах получаем ID с помощью `'parent'   => $current_term->term_id,`

```
$current_term = get_queried_object();

$args = array(
    'number'     => $number,
    'orderby'   => 'title',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'include'   => $ids,
    'parent'   => $current_term->term_id,               
);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

$count = count($product_categories);

if ( $count > 0 ){

   foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {

       echo '<h4><a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></h4>';

       $args = array(

           'posts_per_page' => -1,
           'tax_query' => array(
              'relation' => 'AND',

               array(

                   'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                   'field' => 'slug',
                   // 'terms' => 'white-wines'
                   'terms' => $product_category->slug

                )

           ),

           'post_type' => 'product',
           'orderby' => 'title,'

       );

       $products = new WP_Query( $args );

       echo "<ul>";

       while ( $products->have_posts() ) {

           $products->the_post();

           ?>

               <li>

                   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

                       <?php the_title(); ?>

                   </a>

               </li>
               
           <?php
       }
       echo "</ul>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
<?php
$args = array(
                                 'orderby'   => 'title',
                                 'order'     => 'ASC',
                                 'hide_empty' => false,
                                 'parent' => 0

);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

$count = count($product_categories);

if ( $count > 0 ){

   foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {

        echo '<h4><a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></h4>';
       
        $args = array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                'hide_empty' => false,
                                'parent' => $product_category->term_id,
                                'orderby'   => 'title',
                                'order' => 'ASC'
                             );

       $subcats = get_terms($args);    
       
       foreach ($subcats as $subcat ) :
       
             echo ' - <h5><a href="' . get_term_link( $subcat ) . '">' . $subcat->name . '</a></h5>';
             
             $args = array(
                             'posts_per_page' => -1,
                             'tax_query' => array(
                             'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                    'field' => 'term_id',
                                    'terms' => $subcat->term_id

                                )

                            ),
                            'post_type' => 'product',
                            'orderby' => 'title',
                            'post_status' => 'publish'
                          );

            $products = new WP_Query( $args );

             echo "<ul>";

            while ( $products->have_posts() ) {

                $products->the_post();

                ?>

               <li>

                   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

                       <?php the_title(); ?>

                   </a>

               </li>

                <?php

            }
            
            wp_reset_postdata();

            echo "</ul>";

       endforeach;
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш код. Получается следующие [Скриншот #1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/11fi262epr1e91e/wooc1.png?dl=0)
После попробовал создать дочерние категории и получил такую картину [Скриншот #2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvmfe6hjc5syo4j/wooc2.png?dl=0)
Скорей всего вы меня не правильно поняли. Тот код что я разместил работает корректно и выводит в том виде как надо но с одним но, он выводит все категории магазина которые существуют. Хочется получать список дочерних категорий в зависимости на какой странице нахожусь, если /shop/ то полный список, если /product-category/accessories/ то дочки